# foreach inside tcbitemize

Tags: tcolorbox, foreach

I'd like to use a foreach loop inside the tcbitemize environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}


\begin{tcbitemize}[blanker, raster columns=4, raster equal height=rows]
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}{
\tcbitem {abcd}
}
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

I get the error "Missing number treated as zero"

Can anyone help please?

Thx

Comment: To my knowledge, it's not possible to use `foreach` inside a `tcbitemize` but you can do it with a regular `tcbraster`. https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this satisfy -- from page 312 of the `tcolorbox` manual

https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

You can see the difference by using option `blankest`

The colors

```
   raster every box/.style= {size=small,
                             colframe=red!50!black,
                             colback=red!10!white,
                             valign=center,
                             halign=center}
```

have been added only for emphasis and can be removed/ edited

**MWE without option blankest**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
     \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4, raster equal height,
        raster every box/.style={size=small,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white,
            valign=center,halign=center}]
        
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                \x 
        \end{tcolorbox}}
    
    \end{tcbraster}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**MWE with option blankest**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
     \begin{tcbraster}[blankest, raster columns=4, raster equal height,
        raster every box/.style={size=small,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white,
            valign=center,halign=center}]
        
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                \x 
        \end{tcolorbox}}
    
    \end{tcbraster}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
    
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[blanker, raster columns=4, raster equal height=rows]
    
        \tcbitem \x 
        
    \end{tcbitemize}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Actually not. If I could use the foreach inside the environment, the single tcbitems would be in 4 columns.
Your code instead is generating 4 different tcbitemize environments below of each other.